# Update object identified by composite key with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, key, edit, composite

I have actually a table with components. Each component have a specific version like it is describe above (there are other attributes like name, component_type_id, ...):

id  | version_id

-----+------------

167 |          1

167 |         96

167 |         97

167 |         98

167 |         99

166 |          1

166 |         92

The attributes "id" and "version_id" are a composite primary key, and I want to edit a object by identifying this composite PK.

If I want to update the version 99 of the component #167 =>

With rails when I do :

```
Component.where(id: 167, version_id: 99).first.update({"component_type_id"=>"5", "name"=>"CCC"})
```

Rails do that :

```
SELECT  "components".* FROM "components" WHERE "components"."id" = $1 AND "components"."version_id" = $2  ORDER BY "components"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 167], ["version_id", 99]]

UPDATE "components" SET "name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "components"."id" = 167  [["name", "CCC"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-19 08:05:09.049345"]]
```

**But I want something like that :**

```
UPDATE "components" SET "name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "components"."id" = 167 AND  version_id = 99 [["name", "CCC"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-19 08:05:09.049345"]]
```

Thanks to help me
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these is only one record with the given id and version, Try:

```
Component.where(id: 167, version_id: 99).update_all(component_type_id: 5, name: "CCC")
```

In this way, Rails will not instance a record, avoid your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was so close :)

Comment: I had a other issue, I solve it. I was thinking that I could do exactly the same thing for destroy so I done :

Component.where(id: 167, version_id: 99).destroy_all

But the correct was =====>>

Component.where(id: id: 167, version_id: 99).delete_all

Comment: destroy_all will create record instances and call destroy method on them, and a instance has no knowledge about how it was fetched(the version_id part), it just care about the id. The point is do not get instantiated record.